# How to set auto date increment format in sql to dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: sql

By default the auto increment function sets any date to yyyy/mm/dd. How can I change that column to set the auto increment to dd/mm/yyyy?

This is not a SELECT CONVERT() question, im not asking how to select a column but change the auto increment format.

Comment: is it an sql question?  do u want to make a date field in your table as autoincrement?

Comment: I want to create a column that auto increments the date, but the format needs to be dd/mm/yyyy, by default its yyy/mm/dd.

Comment: Please specify what DB engine is in use.  Also, what type is the column?

Comment: The column type is date. Im not sure what is the DB engine i used the one provided by siteground, phpMyadmin/mysql perhaps

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, since this is a product specific question.

Comment: But whether its a product or not, shouldn't I be able to change the date format when creating a column? regardless of the product,changing the date format in a creation of a column using sql is universal. The date default may be different, but changing the date type manually is the same using sql.

Comment: Dates have no format.  Client software that accesses the database usually does.  Don't worry about it.  However, if you don't know what RDBMS you are using, you are going have difficulty doing almost anything.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored as a number in all databases, so they don't have a format internally. An auto-incremented date will work exactly as a auto-incremented integer for example.
What you are looking at is probably the display preference for the editor you are using to view the database or the default date format of the database when returning data
you may be able to change that default format for the database, or for the column, depending on database engine, etc.

So, no, you can't change the Auto-increment format of a date since that is not what is happening internally. You can change the format the date is displayed or retrieved from the DB.